# Photoshop's "print size" is still not accurate despite changed settings (Photoshop won't use decimals?)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, resolution

Lengthy story here but in short, I followed some tutorials saying that to get an accurate size of your file in Photoshop when using the "print size" option, you divide your screen's current pixel size with the screen's physical horizontal size (in my case 1920px / 52,8 cm = 36.3636...). then you enter it under the menu "screen resolution" and in my case changed the unit to centimeters instead of inches.

After changed settings I start a new A4 sized document (international paper) and use "print size" on it. And when holding an A4 paper (210mm in length) against the screen, the Photoshop file's length is actually 207mm. 
Ok, so I tried to make minor adjustments with the decimals (from 36,36 up to 36,99) but nothing changes until the number becomes 37...then the Photoshop file suddenly decides to change size and jumps up to 213mm instead!! Why? The setting allows 3 digit after the decimal...why can't it use them for minor adjustments??

[image: Print size]

Comment: You **can't** have ".363" of a pixel. Pixels must be whole integers.

Comment: @Scott, yes *pixels* must be integers, but *resolution* can have decimals. For example if I make a 300 *pixels per inch* document and switch to *pixels per centimeter* I get 118,11 ppc.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve (besides the fact that you want Photoshop to show a print document at its actual size). The setting you are changing (*Preferences > Units & Rulers > New Document Preset Resolutions > Screen Resolution*) only affects the resolution of new *screen* documents. You are creating a *print* document. And no matter what the resolution of a document is, 100% zoom will still just show 1 pixels of the document as 1 pixel on the screen. Which zoom are you at when measuring the A4 on the screen?

Comment: In other words: If you are creating an A4 document, you must be trying to create a print document. The resolution of a print document shouldn't be defined to make the document be at scale on your screen. It should be made at the resolution you want to print. Often 300 ppi. So there might be some misunderstanding here?

Comment: Sorry if the question is confusing, I'm fairly new at this with pixels/sizes etc. But I want to have something created in PS and turn it into a printed 3d object on my 3d printer...hence it needs to be as accurate as I can get it.

Comment: I don't know much about 3D print and i might be wrong, but I don't think that a pixel based application like Photoshop is the right tool. It's meant for creating flat 2D images. How will you get depth? By adding layers? I work with print and I only use Photoshop for editing images and drawings. Then I place them in InDesign/Illustrator which are vector based applications where you have much more control over actual physical size. Changing the resolution of your artwork to force it to be displayed to scale on your specific screen does not make it any more accurate.

Comment: I had the same issue and in the end I just found a zoom value that was giving me a 1:1 screen to document size in Photoshop.

Comment: @Wolff merely because some math in some field results in a decimal that does *not* mean a pixel decimal is used. It's rounded. Close the dialog and reopen it... rounded (at least in my experience). Pixels must be whole.

Comment: The software that makes the 3D print is unlikely to care.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Print Size functionality to show the physical size of a print document on screen, follow these steps:

1. Let ***w*** be the width of your screen in cm (obviously you need to measure this with a ruler).
2. Let ***x*** be the width of your screen in pixels (find this in your display settings)
3. Screen resolution = *x* / *w*.  Round the value to the nearest two decimal places. This should be accurate enough.
4. Create a new print document using the print presets in Photoshop, something like an A4 sheet will do. Make sure you set the units to centimetres, and the resolution to 118.11 pixels per centimetre (equivalent to 300ppi).
5. Go into *Preferences > Units and Rulers*, set the screen resolution you calculated in step 3, in pixels per centimetre. The print resolution setting should be 118.11 pixels per centimetre.

Now try *View > Print Size*. Then, with a ruler, measure the width of the sheet on screen. It should be 21cm.

Note: for consistency and to avoid confusion I made all measurements metric, however you can also use imperial measurements if you want. It makes no difference.